# How to compare similarity between two strings (other than English language) in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, distance, jaro-winkler

I want to find the similarity between the two strings
Example

```
string1 = "One"
string2 = "one"
```

And I expect the answer to be between 0 and 1. For the above two strings, we get 1.
Right now I'm using "Jellyfish", a module in python which has the jaro_distance() function.
But the downside is I'm only able to compare two strings that contain only English words and other special characters. But I want to compare two strings in other languages, say Punjabi

```
string1 = "ਬੁੱਧਵਾਰ"
string2 = "ਬੁੱਧਵਾ"
```

I tried the same jaro_distance() function, but I'm getting

```
>>score = jellyfish.jaro_distance(unicode(string1), unicode(string2))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to encode and decode them, before feeding them to the function.
Is there any way to use jaro_distance() for other languages or is there any other module/functions available for this?
Can you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `SequenceMatcher` from the built-in module `difflib`

Code example:

```
import difflib

print(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "ਬੁੱਧਵਾਰ", "ਬੁੱਧਵਾ").ratio())
```

Output:

```
0.9230769230769231
```